# How to remove angular expression attributes from element

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I'd like to know whether it's possible to remove Angular expressions dynamically. 
I tried the following without any success:

**My button**

```
<button myDirective [disabled]="someExpression">Clippy</button>
```

**My Directive**

```
@Directive({
   selector: '[myDirective]'
})
export class MyDirective {
   constructor(private element: ElementRef) {}

   ngOnInit() {
      this.element.nativeElement.removeAttribute('disabled');
   }
}
```

**The problem**

Initially the button won't be disabled, but once `someExpression` re-evaluates it'll add the disabled attribute back to the element.

Just for clarification, I want to remove an Angular expression dynamically. In the above example it's `[disabled]`. But this can be any binding in the future. I want my directive to overrule the existing binding.

Comment: you can achieve this by setting `@Input` property to the custom `directive` and achieve this

Comment: You don't need a Directive to remove [disable] (not for removeAttribute) "someExpression" can be a boolean variable in your component

Comment: @Eliseo no, disabled is just an example. I want my directive to overrule the, in this case, disabled attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As workaround you can try this:

```typescript
@Directive({
  selector: '[myDirective]'
})
export class MyDirective {
  @Input() disabled;

  constructor(private element: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.disabled) {
      this.element.nativeElement.removeAttribute('disabled');
    }
  }
}
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1ubghq?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**

Answer (score 1):

Use @HostBinding, e.g.

```
import { Directive, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[statusDirective]',
})
export class StatusDirective {
  @HostBinding('disabled') disable = true;
  constructor() {}
}

//Your input never enabled
//<input type="text" name="id" [disabled]="false" statusDirective  >
```

Comment: This works untill the expression changes, I think I have to use `ngOnChanges` as posted by @yurzui

Answer (score 0):

```
<button myDirective [disabled]="hideAttr">Clippy - {{hideAttr}}</button>
```

the disabled attribute is not removed when hideAttr is false

https://plnkr.co/edit/h86IUsny6MiLfRI9tsPx

Comment: I know, that's not what I want. I want to remove  the entire binding

Comment: @Dieterg ok Thanks

Comment: you can use @hostBinding

Answer (score 0):

You probably need two copies of the button but only one of them displayed at a time

```
<ng-container *ngIf="showButtonWithDisabledExpr">
        <button [disabled]="someExpression">Clippy</button>
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="!showButtonWithDisabledExpr">
        <button>Clippy</button>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

In newer Angular versions you need to make sure the expression evaluates to null or undefined:

> When the expression resolves to null or undefined, Angular removes the attribute altogether.

See [Attribute Binding](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding#syntax).

So an example would be:

```
<button [disabled]="someExpression ? '' : null">Clippy</button>
```